# Store history data using customization features of a profesionnal software

Tags: database, vbscript

**Context**

My company uses a system that has access to the state of different items in the plant.

This software can be customized, by executing a single VBScript function, at a given interval.

The values taken by different variables in the system can be accessed using `HMIRuntime.Tags("tagName").Read`

**Purpose**

For trending purposes, I would like to store the values of some tags.

**Code**

```
Function action
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForAppending = 8

    Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim objFileToRead : Set objFileToRead = oFS.OpenTextFile(parameterListPath, ForReading)
    Dim params: Set params = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    objFileToRead.SkipLine 'Ditch first line (header)

    Do Until objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
        params.add objFileToRead.ReadLine
    Loop
    objFileToRead.Close

    Dim param, new_value, current_time, objFileToWrite

    current_time = CStr(HMIRuntime.Tags("Time").Read)+","
    For Each param In params
        If Trim(CStr(HMIRuntime.Tags(param).Read)) = "" Then
            new_value = "no_value"
        Else
            new_value = Trim(Replace(CStr(HMIRuntime.Tags(param).Read),Chr(0),Chr(32)))
        End If
        Set objFileToWrite = oFS.OpenTextFile(Replace(archivePath,"{0}",param), ForAppending)
        objFileToWrite.WriteLine current_time + new_value
        objFileToWrite.Close
    Next
End Function
```

**Expected take-ways from the review**

- Performance: The solution I chose, creating, then appending values in a text file is slow as hell, and I would like to improve that (with the limitation of having to use VBScript).
- General quality of the code: As an industrial guy, I know VBA a bit, and I tried to make work with VBScript, but I am sure there is a lot of room for improvement.

Thanks a lot to the reviewers :)

Comment: How big is the `parameterListPath` file (number of lines)? Are there duplicities? Omit building `System.Collections.ArrayList`; instead of `params.add objFileToRead.ReadLine` use `param = objFileToRead.ReadLine` and insert body of the `For Each param In params` loop.